# Failed to read temperature from DHT22 sensor

Tags: arduino, menu, temperature

I'm still new in this field. I make a project and I need to read temperature of the room (box). I try to read temperature using DHT22 sensor, but it alwasy failed. Instead of current temperature, serial monitor shows nan. When I tried to use a simpler code, it works. But when I add it into my menu code, it failed. I don't know whats wrong.
Here's my menu code
`

```
#include "PinChangeInterrupt.h"
#include "DHT.h"
#include "Countimer.h"
#define DHTPIN 5
#define DHTTYPE DHT22

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
Countimer timer;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
  encoder_value();
  int b = checkButton();
  if (b == 1) clickEvent();
  if (b == 2) doubleClickEvent(); 
  if (b == 3) holdEvent(); 
}

void encoder_value() {
  
}

int checkButton() {

}

void clickEvent() {
 
}

void doubleClickEvent() { 
  if (buah == 1){
    set_temperature = 60;
    timer.setCounter(0,0,10, timer.COUNT_DOWN, onComplete);
    timer.setInterval(refreshClock, 1000);
    refreshClock();
    while (!timer.isCounterCompleted()){
      timer.run();
      timer.start();
      PID();
      if(timer.isCounterCompleted()){
        break;
      }
    } 
    onComplete();
    return buahPilih;
  }
  else if (buah == 2){
    
  }
}

void holdEvent() {

}

void refreshClock(){
  Serial.println(timer.getCurrentTime());
}

void PID(){
  float temperature_read = dht.readTemperature();
  Serial.print(temperature_read);
  delay(10000);
}

void onComplete(){

}
```

and here'd the simple code that works when I try to read DHT22

```
#include "DHT.h"
#include "LiquidCrystal_I2C.h"
#define DHTPIN 5
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
#include "RBDdimmer.h"

DHT dht (DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
int fan = 7;

const int zeroCrossPin = 2;
const int adcPin = 3;
dimmerLamp adc(adcPin);
int power;
float set_temperature = 31.6;
float temperature_read = 0.0;
float suhu;
float PID_error = 0;
float previous_error = 0;
float elapsedTime, Time, timePrev;
float PID_value = 0;

int kp = 90;
int ki = 30;
int kd = 80;

int PID_p = 0;
int PID_i = 0;
int PID_d = 0;
float last_kp = 0;
float last_ki = 0;
float last_kd = 0;
int PID_values_fix = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.clear();
  pinMode(fan, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  Serial.print("Suhu : ");
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.println(" C");
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print("Kelembaban : ");
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.println(" %");
  Serial.print(" ");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Suhu: ");
  lcd.print(t);
  //lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("kelem: ");
  lcd.print(h);
  //PIDnyo 
  
  PID_error = set_temperature - t;
  Serial.print("Error terbaca: ");
  Serial.println(PID_error);
  Serial.print(" ");
  PID_p = kp * PID_error;
  PID_i = PID_i +(ki * PID_error);
  timePrev = Time;
  Time = millis();
  elapsedTime = (Time - timePrev) / 1000;
  PID_d = kd * ((PID_error - previous_error) / elapsedTime);
  PID_value = PID_p + PID_i + PID_d;
  Serial.print("PID_value adalah ");
  Serial.println(PID_value);
  Serial.print(" ");
  previous_error = PID_error; //remenber to store previous_error
  //delay(1000);
  //how to keluaran PWM jadi input dimmernyo
  power = PID_value;
  if (power<0){
    power = 0;
  }
  else if (power > 70){
    power = 70;
  }
  else if (0<power<70){
    power = power;
  }
  //how to set value on dimmer
  adc.setPower(power);
  Serial.print("lampValue -> ");
  Serial.print(adc.getPower()); // yg diliatin di serial monitor, berapa persen powernya
  Serial.println("%");
  Serial.print(" ");
  
  if (t > 31){
    digitalWrite(fan, LOW);
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

[here's the result of this code, the right result is the simple one, and the left is the menu that failed to read DHT22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2EUg.png)

Thankyou for the attention, I do hope that I'll find the bugs so that code will work as what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have posted way too much code for anyone to read!

One thing I know with DHT sensors is that you can't read them too quickly or you can get NaN or rubbish values, I think the minimum time you need to wait between reading of the temp/humidity should be at least 2-3 seconds (2000-3000 millis), I normally wait at least 10 seconds.

Check that you are not trying to read them too quickly.

Comment: But, as you can see from the result pict that I attached, the simpler code could read DHT less than a second(?). If I really have to wait at least 10 seconds, should I change temperature sensor that I use since I have to read the temperature every second?

Comment: The spec sheet for DHT22 says it has to be over 2 seconds
Here is the link, it's on page 3:

https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/Digital+humidity+and+temperature+sensor+AM2302.pdf

Also, don't waste your time with the AHT10, it's the same story.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. I'll try to modify my program 

Comment: Sorry for asking again, with the same code as what I attached before, I put the DHT reading into a new function, and I add 5 and even 10 seconds delay in that function. But why does the DHT reading shows nan again?